# Why does xargs split on spaces even with -0?

Tags: xargs

According to the docs and advises on the internet, any of these:

```
$ ls $(env -0 | xargs -0)
$ ls $(env | xargs -d '\n')
```

given `LESSOPEN` is `| %s _=/usr/bin/env` should produce this:

```
...
ls: cannot access 'LESSOPEN=| %s _=/usr/bin/env': No such file or directory
```

but in reality I'm getting this:

```
...
ls: cannot access 'LESSOPEN=|': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '%s': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '_=/usr/bin/env': No such file or directory
```

why does it still splits on whitespace even with `-0` option?

System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

---

**Note.** I'm using `ls` just to expose the arguments. My end goal is like this:

```
docker exec node_container env $(env -0 | grep -z '^SOME_PREFIX_' | xargs -0) yarn build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't split on spaces. **The shell** splits the output of the $(…) expansion on spaces, and xargs can do absolutely nothing about it when it's being used that way.

If you leave any $variable or $(command) expansion unquoted, the shell will *always* split the resulting value into individual words on spaces/tabs/newlines. It doesn't matter that your "inner" command happens to be $(xargs) versus $(anything else), its output will always be re-interpreted by the shell the same way.

In other words, **that's not how you're supposed to use xargs.** Xargs can only do its job properly when it *itself* is allowed to construct the final command line, like this:

```
env -0 | xargs -0 ls
```

Xargs doesn't know how to insert multiple arguments in the middle (by default it can only append, and with `-I` it can only insert one). So in your case, all "trailing" arguments have to be provided as part of xargs *input*:

```
(env -0 | grep -z "^SOME_PREFIX_";
 printf "yarn\0build\0") | xargs -0 docker exec node_container env
```

But at this point it might be better to try non-xargs-based approaches:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This example uses Bash-specific features and won't work with plain sh
args=()
for key in ${!SOME_PREFIX_*}; do
    args+=("$key=${!key}")
done
docker exec node_container env "${args[@]}" yarn build
```

Note that in the last example 'args[@]' is an array variable, therefore double-quoting its expansion will correctly produce one argument for each array item, without any space-splitting. (The difficult part is actually getting some command's output *into* the array. Fortunately, you can gather environment variables using shell internal tools without needing an external command.)

Non-shell languages will also do the job:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
@cmd = qw(docker exec node_container env),
       (map {"$_=$ENV{$_}"} grep {/^SOME_PREFIX_/} keys %ENV),
       qw(yarn build);
system @cmd;
```

Comment: The solution with bash array is quite elegant (in CI/CD people mostly use bash by default). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

what you are trying to do can be achieved by:

```
env -0 | xargs -0 ls
```

Comment: The question is "why?" and your answer doesn't answer this *at all*.

Answer (score -4):

I do not know will this answer suit you, however I have found this:
[Playing with xargs](https://books.google.pl/books?id=yHc5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=Why%20does%20xargs%20split%20on%20spaces%20even%20with%20-0?&source=bl&ots=BZlCq2r21E&sig=ACfU3U0ayDpKPRvvs2B-QccvxYRPCrYxpg&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifrMzz3YDqAhWps4sKHTb7CTQQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Why%20does%20xargs%20split%20on%20spaces%20even%20with%20-0%3F&f=false)

Comment: Link-only answers are low quality.

Comment: One more time I will repeat. Copyrights. I do not see any sense in copy paste method compatriot.

Comment: Then write an original answer? Your link is entirely [inaccessible](https://i.imgur.com/bEJ76d1.png) to many readers because of the same "copyrights".

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time for this. I am to busy to write essays.